# Why is @Inject object(Optional) coming null while running unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, java-8, mockito

I have a class `Room`, where I inject Optional `Person` object, this is coming null while running `testSuccess`. My understanding is it should come non null, since I am setting this to `new Person()` at the start of the test. Why is it coming null?

```
public class Room{

    @Inject
    private Optional<Person> person1 
    //this is coming null when running test

}
```

My unit test

```
public class RoomTest {

    @Inject Mocks
    private Room testRoom

    .....
    //Other mocks

    private Optional<Person> testPerson
    //Not able to mock this since its optional, hence directly setting value in unit test.

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccess() {
         testPerson = Optional.of(new Person());
         ....
         
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-is-my-class-not-using-my-mock-in-unit-test

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, `@InjectMocks` only injects `@Mock`s. The `testPerson` is not a mock. Why not just add an `@Inject`-ing constructor to the `Room` class that would accept a `person`? This way you could just instantiate a `testRoom` in your test method and your dependency injection will still work.

```
public class Room{
    private Optional<Person> person;

    @Inject
    public Room(Optional<Person> person) {
       this.person = person;
    }
}

public class RoomTest {
    @Test
    public void testSuccess() {
         Optional<Person> testPerson = Optional.of(new Person());
         Room room = new Room(testPerson);
         ...
    }

}
```

That said, if you absolutely want to use the annotations and adding the constructor is not an option for you then you can use PowerMock runner to mock the `Optional`. Conceptually, it can look like the code below. But usually, if you have to use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) there might be something wrong with the code :)

```
public class Room{
    @Inject
    private Optional<Person> person;
}

// This is for JUnit4. Using Powermock with JUnit5 will be more involved
@RunWith(PowerMockitoRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Optional.class) // to mock the final class
public class RoomTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private Room testRoom;

    @Mock
    private Optional<Person> testPerson;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccess() {
        ...
    }
}
```